# How can i change the langauge of fragment without changing the phone lang?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, locale

I noticed that my app changes the language only when I change the phone language, but that only for fragments, for activity, it works will

I'm using

```
 private void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale locale= new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config=new Configuration();
        config.locale=locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences("Settings",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Lang",lang);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public void loadLocale(){
        SharedPreferences editor=getSharedPreferences("Settings",Splash.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language=editor.getString("My_Lang","My_Lang");
        Log.d("hahahahahahdhjzshsdj",language);
        setLocale(language);


    }
```

and

```
private void showChangeLanguageDialog() {
        final String[] listLang={"Francais","العربية","English"};
        AlertDialog.Builder onBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);
        onBuilder.setTitle("Choose Language...");
        onBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listLang, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(which==0){
                    setLocale("fr");
                    recreate();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,Splash2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(which==1){

                    setLocale("ar");
                    recreate();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,Splash2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(which==2){

                    setLocale("en");
                    recreate();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,Splash2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog mDialog=onBuilder.create();
        mDialog.show();
    }
```

So, when I run the app, I got an `alertDialog` to choose the language, after choosing it, it got changed the only inactivity but not in a fragment, I have 6 fragments

How can I fix that?

Comment: Could u showcase your fragment class and make sure u have setLocale method in fragment

Comment: what fragment which not be affected? anw, `updateConfiguration` is deprecated method

Comment: @ArunAbimanyu sorry for late, i didn't put setLocale method in fragments, i just put it once in the ifrst screen, then after the user choose the language from alertDialog, an intent opened which is a spalsh screen, then after 4 seconds, it open the fragment, and only the language of the bottom menu is changed because it's activity, but not for fragments

Comment: @GianhTran sorry for the late, yes i know updateConfiguration is deprecated, but, i followed a tutorial from youtube and he said that even, it will still working